# averaging numbers in a column in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, average, bigdecimal

I have a table with a column of floating point numbers. I want to average the numbers in that column.

Per http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Calculations.html I used:

```
Table.average(:column)
```

What I get is:

```
#<BigDecimal:7fcacbbe5eb8,'0.4898731422 50531E3',27(36)>
```

What's the best way to convert that into nearest integer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer to my own question:

```
Table.average(:column).round
```